# angularjs md-select big data

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="someModel" placeholder="Select a user">
   <md-option ng-value="user.id" ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

If the users array has a big size, this works fine with Chrome but causes bad performance with ie11.

Why is that and what are the possible solutions.

Comment: How much data is "big size", and what do you classify as "bad performance"?

Comment: That is because chrome is fast :) I don't know your purpose but if it will be applicable to your project you may consider to use pagination?

Comment: array of 270 elements makes the application very slow but only on ie11

Answer (score 0):

You can handle by using  limitTo and orderby filters,

```
 <md-select ng-model="someModel" placeholder="Select a user">
    <md-option ng-value="user.id" ng-repeat="user in users |limitTo:10">{{user.name}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oa3UUR0ADBrabpOWeGgk?p=preview)**